# how i can lauch my project after i reinstall my windows

Tags: java, android-studio

before i reinstall my windows, i copy all of my project in android studio to my HDD. after reinstalling, i put all of my project to Android Studio Project. but when i try to reinstall android studio, i got the new version (different from my last version) when i try to launch my project there is a problem show in "Build" tap, it tell "Module 'app': platform 'android-29' not found." and

"Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
build-tools;29.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2
platforms;android-29 Android SDK Platform 29
To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Using Android SDK:"

Comment: Have you gone into the SDK manager and tried to install android 29 manually? When you do so, it should prompt you to accept the license agreement.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way is to use your original sdk version. There might exists some comflicts between the latest sdk and your project.